# Adicionar Maven a um Web Application Project

Tags: java, maven

Bom dia, estou usando um Web Application Project, para poder utilizar o Google App Engine.
Gostaria de poder baixar os .jar e suas dependências usando o Maven, alguém sabe como adicionar o Maven ao meu Web Application Project?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven

Comment: mvn archetype:generate -Dappengine-version=1.9.18 -Dapplication-id=contas -Dfilter=com.google.appengine.archetypes:appengine-skeleton-archetype.
Tentei criar o projeto assim, como fala na descrição, deu build success, mas ainda assim deu o erro: 'your filter doesn't match any archetype'.
Como posso corrigir isso? e onde meu projeto vai ser criado, não o encontrei.

Comment: Fiz todo o processo até o 15, consegui criar o projeto.
Só encontrei um problema, quando eu importo o .war para o eclipse, e tento fazer o deploy, ele diz que meu projeto não é um web app project.
Fiz tudo como fala lá, e ainda assim não funcionou, o que esta faltando?

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer se já tem o Maven instalado e configurado na sua máquina e na IDE é clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cima do projeto > Configurar > Converter para Projeto Maven (segue na imagem). Ou antes disso você precisaria configurar o Maven na sua máquina, nas variáveis de ambiente e na sua IDE se necessário, segue o seguinte link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156647/installing-maven.

Se a sua IDE for a Eclipse você pode baixar para esta IDE no Eclipse MarketPlace. Help > Eclipse MarketPlace > Pesquisar por Maven > E instalar o Maven Integration For Eclipse Luna, ou com o nome da versão do seu IDE que pode ser Luna, Kepler, entre outros.

E após isso resta configurar o pom.xml que o Maven gera conforme os frameworks que você precisa utilizar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]